# How can I fetch custom post by custom category id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fetch custom post by custom category id .Post data coming with category .But when I am selecting one category for post it's automatically selected on other category.Problem is that I an not able to assign different post to different category .

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'portfolio', 
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args,'category_name=categories' );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<div class="col-1-3">';
        ?><?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );?>
       <div class="wrap-col">
                        <div class="item-container">
                            <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $thumbnail[0]; ?>" data-fancybox-group= gallery>

                          <div class="overlay text-center">
                            <div class="overlay-inner">
                              <h4>BAKER CANISTER PUMP</h4>
                            </div>
                          </div><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0];?>"></a> </div>
                      </div>
       <?php echo '</div>';
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Here is my custom taxonomies.I am doing all thing good but I do not what is wrong.I am following all method but no success .please help

```
function create_portfolio_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_categories', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//loop the names of the slugs for the portfolio_categories
$terms = get_terms( array ( 'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories', 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $slug = $term->slug;

  $posts_args = array(
    'post_type'         => porfolio,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'tax_query'         => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array (
          'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $slug,
      )
    ),
  );
  $posts_query = new WP_Query( $posts_args );
  if( $posts_query->have_posts() ):
    echo '<div id="' . $slug . '">
        <h1 class="text-center">' . $term->name . '</h1>
            while( $posts_query->have_posts() ): $posts_query->the_post();
              echo '<div>' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
            endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
  endif;
  }
?>
```

Comment: omukiguy@I am using your code but know changes . please check my updated question can you update your answere

Comment: I am using that somewhere. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: omukiguy @iit's still does not showing on id basis , mean if i have two post for category 1 then only show 2 post in category 1 and if I have 3 post in category three then show three post only in category three,@please answre me

Comment: I don't understand your requirement but the code above filters the posts to be queried by the slug of the taxonomy. Say if have under portfolio_categories e.g. nature (2 posts), portraits (2 posts) it will return them in that order. Kindly look at your page source after running this. You can also add other arguments to `$posts_args ` such as order and orderby. Hope that helps